# Graphics To Console

Tags: shell, user-interface, unix, console

im not even sure if what im asking for is possible.

i want to create a really lightweight interface for the RPi. it doesn't needs to should much in terms of graphics, but i would help.

i want to display data onto the unix console (so i don't have to start up a GUI desktop like Gnome).

but i don't even know what to google for what i want. basically, when installing something like Ubuntu, you get the console screen but it slightly formatted  (unlike just logging to the console).

i want to create an interface similar to what might see when you load the BIOS menu. how do i do this?

it would also be really useful if i could get some touch functionality so if i touch certain parts of the screen it would register and i could get the interface to behave as i need it to.

Comment: The search term you're looking for is probably "framebuffer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify a programming language so maybe [dialog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29) will do.
[ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is well known for C.